# Is it possible to layer multiple background images in CSS

Tags: css

For a DIV block can i use multiple background images PNG's with different background position? can it be possible using only CSS & HTML

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before asking a question, please check out [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this what you are referring to? [CSS Multiple Backgrounds](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were asking about?

```css
div {
  height: 320px;
  
  background-image:
    url(https://pngimg.com/uploads/elmo/elmo_PNG90481.png),
    url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/kateph/kateph1803/kateph180300025/97623211-white-clouds-on-the-blue-sky-sky-texture.jpg);
  background-position: center, left top;
  background-size: 320px, 100vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This div has multiple background layers</p>
</div>
```

As BeerusDev said, you can read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp).

Comment: Perfect, this what i was looking for, Thank You